# Does hyperledger fabric v 1.4 support python for developing client applications

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I tried the sample application in the link https://github.com/IBM/evote/blob/master/docs/run-local.md . Am able to run it locally. But my requirement is to use python in the middle layer instead of node js. We are trying to develop a POC using python rest API. In the documentation, i can see only node.js examples and references for new programming model for fabric. Does Fabric 1.4 support Python ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python SDK here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py

I don't know how upto date this sdk is regarding giving access to the full capabilities of the CA, Peer and Orderer at 1.4 or 2.0. I do know that it doesn't contain the higher level apis represented by Gateway/Network/Contract which exist in the node sdk, java sdk (and plans to add it to the Go SDK as well)

Comment: Thanks @david_k for your answer !! That helps.